# Bootstrap3 navbar-form does not resize in Firefox

Tags: css, joomla, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a problem in Firefox with the size of a search form when screen have 768px or low, it does not fix the width of the form. Chrome does it good.

[image]

The css is the standard Bootstrap 3 files, but firefox opens bootstrap.css:null wihle chrome opens navbar.less and utilities.less

Here is the code:

```html
<div class="pull-right">
  <form class="navbar-form navbar-search" action="/portal/index.php/es/" method="post" role="search">
    <div class="input-group">
      <input name="searchword" id="mod-search-searchword" maxlength="200" class="form-control" type="search" size="20" placeholder="Buscar...">
        <div class="input-group-btn">
          <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i>
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    <input type="hidden" name="task" value="search">
    <input type="hidden" name="option" value="com_search">
    <input type="hidden" name="Itemid" value="102">
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your use of `pull-right` on the initial element is causing the problem. Replacing this with `text-right` will acheive the same effect (ie. Search box aligned to the right) but columns will work as expected...

[DEMO](http://www.bootply.com/fqLKotY4Sx)

```
<div class="text-right">
  <form class="navbar-form navbar-search" action="/portal/index.php/es/" method="post" role="search">
    ...
  </form>
</div>
```